# python manage.py startapp is not creating migrations directory

Tags: django

**python manage.py startapp polls**. I tried this command but it creates only python files and it does not create the migrations directory. And the django version that i am using is 1.6.11
here is the directory structure of polls directory created by above command

```
__init__.py
admin.py
models.py
test.py 
urls.py
views.py
```

Comment: in 1.6 it wont be created, try using the latest version, unless there is some problem to use it, else you need to create migrations folder and create a blank init.py file inside it

Comment: Are you using south to manage migrations then you need to issue `python manage.py schemamigration polls --initial` this will create migration for you

Comment: after which version migration directory is created by itself ? @Exprator

Comment: 1.7 and later bro @ArvindJha

Comment: You should definitely not be using Django 1.6.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason why a new project should use 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Built-in support for migrations was added in Django 1.7.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations

For Django < 1.7, use south.

South documentation: http://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Hope this helps.